# "number of students rises up slightly" – is this correct?

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence correct? "From 1995 to 2002 the number of students rises up slightly but hold steady from 2002 to 2005"

Comment: *Rises up* sounds strange. I would recommend *rises slightly* instead.

Comment: Are you asking about the shift from singular ("rises") to plural ("hold") verbs with the same subject ("number of students") or about something else? Please try to compose a question heading that will give other site users a sense of what your question is about.

Comment: I doesn't know if it's correct that the subject of the phrases is students or numbers. In Italian it's different!

Comment: Additionally, Sebastian, "rises" and "up" mean essentially the same thing, here---no need for both. I would suggest removing "up."

Comment: Yeah, I think the same applies to 'steady'.  You're fighting that classic conflict: "sounds nice" vs "redundant".  Concision is desired in an educational setting, but I like to read things until they sound **smooth**, bud.  You just have to figure out your audience in these situations because you're correct regardless of whether or not you include the prepositions. If you want to really go concise, you don't need 'slightly', either.

Answer (score 3):

From 1995 to 2002, the number of students rises up slightly but **holds** steady from 2002 to 2005.

The subject of the sentence is "number," not "students," so you want the singular verb "holds" (Note that "rises" is singular as well).

Comment: If you're looking for more information, Grammarbook has some great rules to guide subject/verb agreement: http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp Your question involves Rule 1, but I've found all the rules to be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

All verbs in a sentence should agree with the subject.  The subject is "number", which "rises" and "holds".  I would suggest changing one of your verbs as well to something simpler.  Also, changing your second half of the sentence to be dependent on the rest helps create better flow for sequential data.

> From 1995 to 2002, the number of students increases, before holding steady for three years.